# Online Yeshivot for Baalei Teshuva

Tags: yeshiva-school, baal-teshuva

Does anyone have recommendations for a friend who is looking for an online Baal Teshuva focused Yeshiva?

Note: Ideally they would like it to be Chabad focused and also include learning Hebrew (they said their Hebrew is very beginner).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the challenge is that few yeshivot have full time learning schedules online, due to the importance of learning in havrutot and to be close to teachers. You will find relevant answers for in person programs [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29670/english-speaking-yeshivoth-for-beginners) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126355/help-identifying-yeshivot-for-baalei-teshuva-men/126359#126359)

Comment: Personally I'd be comfortable saying this website matches that description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these Chabad options for you as per you’re request, although the online “Smicha” or rabbinical ordination programs are only for advanced students. There are also other excellent options that are not Chabad affiliated, just google “virtual online yeshiva”.

https://www.jnet.org/

https://irguntorah.org/

https://www.theyeshiva.net/

https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/video_cdo/aid/1106330/jewish/Yeshiva.htm

https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/video_cdo/aid/2530155/jewish/ChabadU.htm

https://onlinesmicha.com/

https://onlinemachon.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMInqHt7IKM9wIVSvSzCh1XwADKEAAYASAAEgJAFPD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jnet.org/

Or call https://mayanot.edu/ and see what they suggest.